# Formation of electromagnetic waves

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

im learning about electromagnetic wavesa t the moment. I would like to check my understanding of how waves are generated and received by mediums.

On the left side, an AC voltage source oscillates an electron within a metal conductor, in space on the right side is another metal conductor with free electrons

When the EM wave is generated by oscilating the electron, how does the electron on the right side become affected?

Is it initially the electorn on the left side has an electric field and exerts a force on the electron on the rightside and when the electron is oscillated the direction of the force on the rightside electron changes|?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds a little as if you're assuming that the transmission of electromagnetic waves could essentially boil down to electrostatic forces.

The answer is no.

At their core, electromagnetic waves result from:

- the capacity of non-static electric fields (i.e. varying with time) to  generate magnetic fields (and conversely).
- The capacity of these mutual field generations to form composite (electric / magnetic) waves === electromagnetic waves which can propagate in the vacuum with no other substate or medium than themselves.

The way time variable electric fields transform into time variable magnetic fields, which in turn generate again time variable electric fields, etc. in an endless cycle is the basis of the phenomenon of electromagnetic waves.

The laws governing these relationships and the resulting waves are given by Maxwell's equations.

[image]

Comment: No, im asking how does the receiving electron almost instantaneously mirror the movement of the transmitter electron? There must be a force in which it experiences, im asking if this is caused by the varying electric field generator at the transmitter. Since electric fields propagate into space, before the variation of the electron at the transmitter it already experiences its electric field, so is this force caused by varying the field? If not, exactly what causes the receiver electron's varying position?

Comment: The electrons in the receiving circuit see the transmitted electromagnetic wave when it arrives at said receiving circuit. In particular, they see the influence of the received electrical component thereof as in a linear antenna: https://home.zhaw.ch/kunr/NTM1/literatur/Rhode_Schwarz_Antenna_Basics.pdf